# Move field from one column to another if empty in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Below is a table im working with. I would like to take the field from [Field1] column and move directly across to [Field2] column.

Results would be like this

Field2

```
Browser
com.android.browser
com.android.browser.BrowserActivity

Email
com.android.email
com.android.email.activity.Welcome

Phone
com.android.contacts
com.android.contacts.activities.PCUDialtactsActivity

Gallery
com.android.gallery3d
com.android.gallery3d.app.Gallery

Táº¯t mÃ n hÃ¬nh
com.katecca.screenofflockdonate
com.katecca.screenofflockdonate.MainHelper

Messaging
com.android.mms
com.android.mms.ui.ConversationList

Simple mode
com.pantech.app.skysettings.simplemode
com.pantech.app.skysettings.simplemode.simplemodesettingshrotcutActivity
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might do what you need:

```
SELECT iif(isnull(Field2), Field1, Field2) as [yourColumnTitle] 
FROM yourTableName
```

Aside from this you'll need to add a column to the table datatype=YesNo and set it to true on the rows you want to affect, then you can

```
SELECT iif(NewColumn <> 0, Field1, Field2) as [yourColumnTitle]
FROM yourTableName
```